# Partial match search of an array (CSV FILE)

Tags: php, arrays, csv, search, partial

I want to have partial search on my CSV file. Here is a sample:

order1223445, DemoName1, MyLocal Address 1, R123456789

order12235443, DemoName2, MyLocal Address2 , W123456789

order1223254, DemoName3, MyLocal Address 3, T123456789

I was able to search it on exact word but not in partial

```
while($row = fgetcsv($ch)) {

    if (in_array($regValue, $row)) {
        echo '<div>' . implode(' | ', $row) . ' </div>';
    }
}
```

So if I input order1223445 it will show the whole row.

order1223445, DemoName, MyLocal Address, 123456789

But if I input order122 or mylocal

Nothing is shown

Comment: Can you be more specific about what programming language or analysis tool you're working with?  E.g., R, Python, Excel, Matlab, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) could be a solution.

```
while($row = fgetcsv($ch)) {

    $matched = FALSE;

    foreach ($row as $column){

        $regular_expression = sprintf("/%s/",$regValue);

        if (preg_match($regular_expression,$column)){
            $match=TRUE;
        }      
    }

    if ($match) {
        echo '<div>' . implode(' | ', $row) . ' </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: jbrahy Thank you so much for your help :) thank you thank you so much